# Powershell client for Azure Durable Function Async HTTP API]

Tags: powershell, azure-durable-functions

I need to call a [Azure Durable Function Async HTTP API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=in-process%2Cv3-model%2Cv1-model&pivots=csharp#async-http) from a Powershell Script.

Is there a higher Level Powershell client, that waits the execution and gives me the output or does I need to implement a call loop calling the status URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PowerShell client for Azure Durable Function Async HTTP API:

*You can use below sample script to call durable function Http API:*

```
$instanceId = "4364b248748e40ca91ba4459f34313d5"
$Url = "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/$instanceId?taskHub=TestHubName&connection=Storage&code=MCxaLIQVPa9LMG7ZZfdpf0jpGWtii2uIMc_r3BzdAekkAzFumoCGFQ=="
$res = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get
if($res.runtimeStatus -ne "Running/Completed"){
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
write-output "not yet completed"
}
else{
$output = $res.output
write-output $output
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

*You can get an instance ID from the Durable function orchestrator as shown:*

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-js-vscode?pivots=nodejs-model-v3) on how to create Azure durable functions from Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no higher level method available. I changed to code to use the `Retry-After` Header for the sleep duration.